# Custom Cells and detail Text Label

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

Just wanna ask this question. Can I use detailTextLabel in a Custom Cell? I wanna have additional info to be displayed in my custom cell. When I tried to use the detailTextLabel, nothing is displayed.

The custom cell .m codes:

```
- (void)setUseDarkBackground:(BOOL)flag{
if (flag != useDarkBackground || !self.backgroundView)
{
    useDarkBackground = flag;

    NSString *backgroundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:useDarkBackground ? @"BGDark" : @"BGLight" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImagePath] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:1.0];
    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
    self.backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.backgroundView.frame = self.bounds;
}}
```

Comment: How did you add your detailed text label?

Comment: I did not add a detailed text label. The detailTextLabel is a property in the UITableviewCell class. So I wanted to know if its possible to use that property in the Custom Cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display additional details, you can take one more UILabel in your custom cell

Comment: I see, but if this custom cell does not have an xib? it is using only .h and .m files... what should I do? Its a passed-down project. I am modifying it

Comment: You can allocate UILabel in .m of customcell like lblDetailedInfo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,20)]; and [self.contentView addSubview:lblDetailedInfo];

Comment: since it does not have a xib file, how can I use addSubview method?

Comment: if xib is not there, you can not add subview dynamically by allocating memory of UIs

Comment: Exactly, so how do I tackle this problem? I have added the .m in the custom cell. At least the actions done, see if you can advice how do I add a label in it

Comment: http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html check this link

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the  [`detailTextLabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/detailTextLabel) of `UITableViewCell`.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *detailTextLabel
```

Have look to blog post for using `detailTextLabel` with cell.

[Show multiline text cells in UITableView](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/11/show-multiline-text-cells-in.html)

Comment: I know about `detailTextLabel` of `UITableViewCell`. I want to use that in my custom cell which is not working

Comment: @Melvin Lai: Did u set the frame for `detailTextLabel` ?

Comment: Try with setting background to  visble color , i will tell us the location of label in cell ...  use  `detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] ;`

Comment: I am using custom cell, there is no label inside it. detailTextLabel isn't going to work at all

Comment: One suggestion .. Create your own `UILabel`  and add that as `subview` of your cell.

Comment: I have edited the custom cell codes in. Apparently, it does not have a xib to add a UILabel.

Comment: @Jhaliya let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1044/discussion-between-melvin-lai-and-jhaliya)